# npx babel not reading configuration from babel.config.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, npx, babel-cli

When running `npx babel index.js` from the command line, I was hoping I would see my babel configurations being applied from babel.config.js

However it does not seem the case as was wondering why this might be?

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function babel(api) {
 api.cache(true);
   return {
     presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
     plugins: [
       [
         'babel-plugin-root-import',
         {
           rootPathSuffix: './src',
           rootPathPrefix: '~/',
         },
       ],
     ],
   };
 };

// index.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from '~/App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent("App Name", () => App)

// Expected output from npx babel index.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App'; // Note the change from '~' to './src' using babel-plugin-root-import
AppRegistry.registerComponent("App Name", () => App)
```

I noticed in the npx babel --help it stated that --no-babelrc flag ignores configuration from .babelrc and .babelignore files. Does this suggest that babel.config.js files aren't considered when calling this command?

Cheers

Comment: Babel version ?

Comment: `npx babel --version` gave 6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`babel.config.js` [config change](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration-api#config-changes) is introduced in babel 7; so if you are using babel 6.*, it doesn't understand [project wide configuration](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#project-wide-configuration) yet; either use `.babelrc` or [upgrade to babel 7](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration) to be able to use new features; I'd did the upgrade its pretty smooth and painless, just make sure you have clean git directory ( in case of emergency :) and do it.